# HashMap<String,List<String>> to HashMap<Object,List<String>> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a HashMap which contains a key: String ( name of object be instantiated ) and Value: List ( variables for the instantiated object)

My current method :

```
public Map<Room,List<String>> buildRoomObjects(Map<String,List<String>> map){

        List<Room> rooms = map.keySet().stream().map(Room::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Map<Room,List<String>> newmap = new HashMap<>();

        for ( Room room : rooms){

            newmap.put(room,map.get(room.getName()));
        }

       return  newmap;
    }
```

Can I avoid the use of the enhanced for Loop here and condense to a single stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stream the [entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) and then use [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-). Use the lambda expression `entry -> new Room(entry.getKey())` to map `Room` as key and then corresponding value

```
Map<Room, List<String>> newmap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> new Room(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

In case if you might have any duplicates keys then you can use `toMap` with `BinaryOperator`

> If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), an IllegalStateException is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use [toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead.